# Ampscript code to cut part from string

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, tracking

I created a code to take the utm and cut it specifically in the campaign part of the utm and return only it. this code works as long as the utm campaign comes first. But I also need to consider that the utm campaign can come from any position. for example, it can come after other utms. Does anyone have any idea how I can get part of a string regardless of the order it comes in?

Below is my code:

```ampscript
/* BANNER RESGATE*/

set @data_disparo = FormatDate(now(),"dd/MM/yyyy")



/*Here in this variable I store the link that has the utm that I want to search for*/

Set @RESGATE_BANNER_LINK = LOOKUP("TB_Blocos_Promocionais_Jornadas","RESGATE_BANNER_LINK","DATA_DISPARO",@data_disparo)



/*Point markings to substring the utm and get only the utm campaign*/

 set @A = IndexOf(@RESGATE_BANNER_LINK,'&')
 
  set @A2 = IndexOf(@RESGATE_BANNER_LINK,'=')

  set @A3 = Subtract(@A,@A2)


/* Here I get the utm campaign */

set @utm_campaign =  Substring(@RESGATE_BANNER_LINK,Add(1,IndexOf(@RESGATE_BANNER_LINK,"=")),Subtract(@A3,1))



/*

The link with the utms from which I want to get only the utm campaign regardless of the order in which it comes is something like this:


https://www.test.com.br/?utm_campaign=This_Is_A_test1&utm_source=email&utm_medium=nda_nda&utm_content=This_Is_A_test2&utm_term=nda_nda_nda_id_200


In this case the utm campaign comes first and the code works. But I need it to work even when the utm campaign comes after any other in the link

*/
```

Comment: Yes, using substring and regex. Please share your code and what you came up with so that we can help you.

Comment: Yes please share script and example as @zuzannamj said, without this, the question is too vague for us to really assist.

Comment: Hi, Guys. I shared my code. I hope you can understand better my question. @zuzannamj

Answer (score 0):

So the simplest way to do this is to separate out the query string and then turn it into a Rowset utilizing the AMPscript function BuildRowsetFromString(). From that you iterate through the RS looking for the utm_campaign label and then from there you substring to get just the value and then you are all set.

See below for example:

```ampscript
                         
%%[
SET @url = "https://www.test.com.br/?utm_source=email&utm_medium=nda_nda&utm_content=This_Is_A_test2&utm_campaign=This_Is_A_test1&utm_term=nda_nda_nda_id_200"

SET @QryStrIndex = IndexOf(@url,"?")

SET @QryStr = SUBSTRING(@url,ADD(@QryStrIndex,1))

SET @QryRS = BUILDROWSETFROMSTRING(@QryStr,"&")

FOR @i=1 TO RowCount(@QryRS) DO
  SET @Row = ROW(@QryRS,@i)
  SET @Field = FIELD(@Row,1)
  SET @utmLabel = "utm_campaign="
  SET @campaignIndex = IndexOf(@field,@utmLabel)
  
  IF @campaignIndex > 0 THEN
    SET @campaignVal = SUBSTRING(@Field,ADD(LENGTH(@utmLabel),1))
    OUTPUT(CONCAT("CampaignValue: ", @campaignVal, "<br>"))
  ENDIF
NEXT @i
]%%
```

Which would output: `CampaignValue: This_Is_A_test1`

Here is a **[link](https://mcsnippets.herokuapp.com/s/xdU6atwd)** to an output in MCSnippets by Pato Sapir that I created to test this out. (I do not know how long those links stay alive for, so you might need to copy/paste above code in despite the direct link)

Comment: Thank you, it worked